# Laravel 5.2 - installing packages issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I've installed the [bootstrap plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap) within Laravel project by composer using this cmd command:

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0-alpha.3
```

**Problem** is:

1) I'm new to laravel and searched a lot for this problem, every this I found is about using `nmp` command and I'm using **Windows** not **Mac**

2) I didn't have any bootstrap files in the public folder. this structure is not found:

```
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

**how** to load bootstrap from vendor to my blade ?

**what** is the difference between downloading bootstrap files manually and installing it with composer? and how to integrate the bootstrap files in my blade any way ?

**same problem** with installing *[blogify](https://packagist.org/packages/jorenvanhocht/blogify)* and *[AdminLTE](https://packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte)*.. can't use any package that downloaded with composer

Used:

Windows 10
XAMP

Comment: To include a css file (in your case bootstrap), simply include the CSS file in your blade template... Of course, you need to put the files in the 'public' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to load bootstrap from vendor to my blade ?

As the [manual](https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap) mentions, you have more options to install bootstrap.

> ```
> Download the latest release.
> Clone the repo: git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git.
> Install with Bower: bower install bootstrap.
> Install with npm: npm install bootstrap@3.
> Install with Meteor: meteor add twbs:bootstrap.
> Install with Composer: composer require twbs/bootstrap.
> ```

Try other options too, if you have any installed.

The goal is to get the files into the /public folder, from where you can access those files from browser and the HTML can work properly.

> what is the difference between downloading bootstrap files manually
>   and installing it with composer? and how to integrate the bootstrap
>   files in my blade any way ?

Nothing much. Composer, npm, bower and others will download the files from repository to the folder where you have run the command.

So run those commands in **public** folder.

*You did not mention if there were any errors or something that could refer to an uncompleted operation.*

If commands do not work, you still have manual download, which - as already told - should be saved to the public folder.

Your *index.blade.php* should have the following in the  tag:

```
<link href="<?php echo url("css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" stylesheet'      type='text/css'>
```

or using [elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#plain-css)

```
<link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: so the thing is this,, composer is only for download but then I have to cut the files from vendor and place it in my public folder. Am I getting you right ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. 

- Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage (install/update) them for you.

Comment: vendor folder should not be edited, untill you know what you are doing. As already told, put files as bootstrap into the laravels public folder.

Comment: From laravels documentation: The public directory contains the front controller and your assets (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.). 

And thats what bootstrap is.

Comment: should I do so with *blogify* and *AdminLTE* ? and really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: No. blogify is an laravel package, bootstrap is an independent framework. Bootstrap works with HTML, so it just needs to be placed in the right folder. 

For blogify, check the docs @ http://www.blogify.io/docs   

AdminLTE works in the same way as Bootstrap. So it goes to the public folder indeed.